# Deque reusable cell without switch in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed that while adding more and more cell types to UICollectionView it's harder to maintain code. So according to principles that we should not change code while adding new features, instead we should add new code.

Let's begin with example.

We have such data model:

```
protocol Animal {}

class Dog: Animal {}

class Duck: Animal {}
```

And we have two appropriate cells - `DogCell` and `DuckCell`.

According to many tutorial we could implement something like this in function from `UICollectionViewDataSource`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let animal = self.animals[indexPath.row]
    if let dog = animal as? Dog {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DogCell", for: indexPath)
    } else if let duck = animal as? Duck {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DuckCell", for: indexPath)
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Now we want to add another cell which is `CatCell` based on `Cat` model.

It's bad practice to add another `else if` for cleaner code, so how to do it in iOS? Are there any good design patterns for that? Objective-C code will be appreciated too.

Comment: I would say that using else-if statements is actually probably the best (plus easiest) way to go. If you think about it, I don't think the problem is with adding more else-if statements, but rather with adding more classes. The more classes you add, the more custom cells you have to design. The else-if statements are more of a symptom of this usage of code.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice for clean code. Do have any examples of bigger projects with such many if-else statements in collectionView method?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new protocol that has a computed String variable for the cell's identifier.

```
protocol AnimalCell {
    var cellReuseIdentifier: String { get }
}
```

Have the Animal protocol conform to the procol.

```
extension Animal: AnimalCell { }
```

And add the cellReuseIdentifier to the classes

```
extension Dog: Animal {
    var cellReuseIdentifier: String {
        return "DogCell"
    }
}

extension Duck: Animal {
    var cellReuseIdentifier: String {
        return "DuckCell"
    }
}
```

Then, you simply set the `cellReuseIdentifier` as the identifier.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let animal = self.animals[indexPath.row]
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: animal.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that classes which are strictly model classes should not keep information about cells because they are used sometimes with no relation to UICollectionView?

Comment: That's why you put it in an extension.  You have only two choices: some kind of map, whether encoded in if-else or a switch, or putting the knowledge into the classes themselves.  Anything you come up with is a variation of those two approaches.  So it depends on how pure you want to be, and what seems uglier or less maintainable.

Comment: I agree with @Avi. I also think, that there is nothing wrong with storing information about UI related stuff in the class itself, if the information is specific to the class. As a suggestion, you could put the `AnimalCell` protocol and the extensions above in a separate file, maybe the file for the cell, to show that it is UI related.

Comment: And remember that reuse identifiers are arbitrary. You can use the actual model class name as your reuse identifier if you want, then you can just say `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: type(of:animal)))`